# Does copay accepts multiple payments?

Tags: address-generation, bip32-hd-wallets, copay

I am a bit confused as to whether copay wallet accepts multiple payments to a single address based on the phrasing "wallet generates new addresses automatically once you use a bitcoin address once"...if tracking is not an issue I suppose the same address can be sent out to several payees right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, once you have generated an address, you can have people send any number of transactions to that address from then on.  I just tried it with Copay on testnet and it works fine.

It automatically generates a new address when a transaction arrives, just to encourage you to use fresh ones if possible, for privacy.  But previous ones continue to work indefinitely.

(Interestingly, it generates a new address whenever a transaction is received, even if that transaction was sent to an older address and the previously displayed address hadn't been used at all.)

Comment: Thank you Nate, tried it over testnet too. I was trying to see whether the address generation can be applied irrespective of payment received yet...thanks for the feedback